# LWC: Find out if a flow is moving back or forward

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have a LWC inside of a flow. I need to notify the LWC if the user has pressed the "Previous" or "Next" button of the flow.

Right now I am using `disconnectedCallback()` for that reason but it triggers for both "Previous" and "Next" button clicks.

Is there a way to communicate this between the flow and the LWC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A component cannot specifically tell if the user moved forward or backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement in some cases. Suppose a flow like this: Screen 1 --> Screen 2 that contains your lwc --> Screen 3.

1. In your lwc, create a parameter

```
 <property name="isPrevious" type="Boolean" label="Does the user click Previous to enter this screen?"/>
```

2. In your lwc, add code below:

```
    @api
    validate() {
      this.isPrevious = true;
      return { isValid: true };
    }
```

If the method validate() already exists, just add the line this.isPrevious = true; right before the line return { isValid: true};

3. Add an Assignment element in the flow between Screen 1 and 2. So the flow now looks like this:
   Screen 1 --> Assignment --> Screen 2 --> Screen 3
4. Create a new variable isGoingBack and in Assignment, set the value to **false**. In Screen 2, assign isGoingBack to the lwc parameter isPrevious.
5. Now in your lwc (eg. in connectedCallback()), you can check isPrevious to tell if the user clicked Previous button to invoke the lwc.

```
    if (this.isPrevious) {//user clicked Previous
```

Note: you need to pick "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow" under Advanced --> Revisited Screen Values of the lwc properties in Screen 2.